# ipad showing NaN while using math.floor javascript

Tags: javascript, ipad

Here is my piece of code please help me out. this working fine for desktop browser

```
var targetduration = 0;
var breaktime = 0;

targetduration += (moment(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')+' '+val[1])). diff(moment(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')+' '+val[0]),'minutes');
breaktime+=  (moment(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')+' '+nextval[0])). diff(moment(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')+' '+val[1]),'minutes');

targetduration = parseInt(targetduration);
breaktime = parseInt(breaktime);

$( '#swipe-'+nameofweek+' ' +'.workinghours').text( Math.floor(targetduration/60)+'h'+' '+Math.floor(targetduration%60)+'m ');
$( '#swipe-'+nameofweek+' ' +'.pause').text( Math.floor(breaktime/60)+'h'+' '+ Math.floor(breaktime%60)+'m ');
```

Thank you :)

Comment: `breaktime` or `targetduration` are not what you expect, on iPad. Validate them

Comment: @Adelin , Please help me, how to achieve

Comment: and a piece of advice, if you're going to post more on StackOverflow - we have no idea what that code does or what those variable are out of context. Add [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Adelin, I have updated my question

Comment: Avoid using so long expressions, which are full of assumptions. Somewhere in that expression a variable is not what you expect. **validate** your code.

Comment: @Adelin, but this is working fine for desktop browser only other than ipad

Comment: maybe because `val[1]` is a value you'd expect (or `nextval[0]`). But, as you can see, they are not evaluated the same on iPad.

Comment: @Adelin, I use document.wirte(targetduration) and document.write(breaktime), and these variables are giving accurate value on ipad as well. but math.floor did wrong something with these variables on ipad.

Comment: `NaN` means the division took place between a number and not a number. To know why, you need to follow the breadcrumbs. `breaktime` gets changed in the meantime. Or is a string, etc.